# I need to select only the field that has only the data

Tags: mysql

```
create table test (txt1 int(3) not null,txt2 int(3) not null, txt3 int(3) not null)
```

Now if I insert a record in this table like.

```
insert into test ('txt1','txt2','txt3') values(25,null,null),(78,null,null)
```

From the above queries table is created and inserted with couple of records. Can any one kindly give me solution how to create query to display the field only that contains records. If the field contain null values the its should not display.

Comment: How can any of the columns be NULL? You've defined the columns as NOT NULL in the CREATE statement.

Comment: by default the fields should hold null value, when value is inserted to the respective field changes from null to given value.                                               now the field that holds only the value should be display

Comment: So is your CREATE TABLE script wrong?

Comment: so kindly suggest me to create query that hold null as its default value.         I am just a beginner in this,  Thks for quick reply

Comment: I have few other clarification can u help me out with that.                                  
                                                                                                                 
 -Two tables created with some fields has a null value by default .     
                                                                                                           
-Now with a single query is it possible to merge two table into a single table and eliminate  the field that hold null value as record.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to run a query whose result does not display the word "NULL" for a missing number value, but displays white space, then in MySQL you may use this formula:

```
IFNULL(FORMAT(txt2, 3, 0), '')
```

FORMAT converts the number to a string of 3 digits.  However, if the number is NULL then the result is a NULL string.  Then the formula IFNULL() returns its first term unless that is NULL, in which case the second term appears instead.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT * FROM [ table name] 
WHERE [column names which could be NULL] IS NOT NULL ;
```

`IS NOT NULL` is a keyword in SQL which is used to neglect NULL fields.